# Python and C++ (Pybind11): Python Extension Module Import Error

Tags: python, c++, python-import, pybind11

I try to wrap a *C++ - function* with `pybind` to create a **python-module**. After compiling with Visual Studio I accomplished to create a *`.pyd`* file. 
I tried to import this file (*python>>> import pymodule*) but get this error:

```
Import Error: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_pymodule)
```

Is it usually the right approach to import a `.pyd` file the way I explained above? Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a) You have to copy the .pyd file into the Python-installation folder (Lib-> side packages).
1b) You can open Python in the same folder where the .pyd - file is placed.

2) the python module must have the same name as the directory defined in CMake